# Passing a value from javascript to jsp image ID

Tags: javascript

```
var text1="hi bye";
document.getElementById("image").value=text1;
```

Here I need to pass this text1 value to "image" ID in jsp. It is working fine in Mozilla, but not working in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the full name like:

```
document.forms['formname']['fieldname']
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById
```

Comment: previously it was working in mozila nt in chrome, if i include the above line it s nt working in mozila

Comment: i have assigned input type="image" in jsp page. if i assign  type="text" it is working fine in all browsers...please help me

Comment: What is your element? a text field?

Comment: There is no type image AFAIK, take alook here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp depending on which HTML you are using, in the HTML5 there are some more type attributes but there still not image one, for images you can use the image tag

Comment: i have used type as image ...i saw type="image " in w3schools

Comment: thats nice. please consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.